# Proof of inequality $\lceil x \rceil \le x+1$

Tags: master-theorem

I went through the Master Theorum extension for floors and ceiling section **4.6.2** in the book **Introduction to Algorithms**

It had the following statement:

> Using the inequality $\lceil x \rceil \le x+1$

But I haven't seen the inequality anywhere and could not understand the verifiability of inequality.

Instead the Chapter Floors and ceilings defined floors and ceilings as:

$$x-1 \lt \lfloor x \rfloor \le x \le \lceil x \rceil \lt x+1 $$

Please clear my doubt over this.

On how to use this identity and which identity to be considered when because both of them define completely different inequalities.

Thank you.

Comment: The inequality $\lceil x \rceil < x+1$ is stronger than $\lceil x \rceil \leq x+1$, but both are valid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The definition of $\lceil x \rceil$ is:

> $\lceil x \rceil$ is the minimal integer $n$ such that $n \geq x$.

(The existence of such an integer makes the reals an *Archimedean* field.)

Let us assume, for the sake of contradiction, that $\lceil x \rceil \geq x + 1$. Then $\lceil x \rceil - 1 \geq x$. Since $\lceil x \rceil - 1$ is also an integer, this contradicts the definition of $\lceil x \rceil$. Thus $\lceil x \rceil < x + 1$.

It is also easy to check that the inequality is tight, in the sense that $1$ cannot be replaced by any smaller $\theta$. Indeed, if $\theta = 1 - \epsilon$ for $\epsilon \in (0,1)$, then $\lceil \epsilon \rceil = 1 = \epsilon + \theta$.

Comment: AFAIK the contradiction proves that the inequality is wrong isn't it.

Comment: No, the inequality is correct.

Comment: Okay but the chapter floors and ceilings gave a different perspective on floors and ceilings.

Comment: You asked how to prove the inequality $\lceil x \rceil < x + 1$, I gave the proof. You also asked other questions, but (1) they were rather unclear, and (2) the usual rule is one question per post.

Comment: If you have any further questions, please ask them separately.

Comment: Well I asked the proof for : $\lceil x \rceil \le x + 1$. Sorry if it appears unclear.

Comment: I gave you a proof for a stronger inequality, $\lceil x \rceil < x + 1$.

Comment: @SachinBahukhandi $a \leq b$ is usually defined as $(a < b) \lor a = b$. Hence to show $a = b$ or $a < b$ is enough to show $a \leq b$.

Comment: You mean that $a \leq b$ follows from $a < b$, or from $a = b$. In particular, if we know that $a < b$, then it follows that $a \leq b$.

Comment: Ohh okay okay. Now I got it. Thank you.

Comment: I was confused because not on a single instance I could verify that $\lceil x \rceil=x+1 $ so i was confused.